# Yii2 HTML purifier

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

I've got a question about Yii2's validation. So, my model validation rule's something like this:

```
return [
    ['status', 'required', 'on' => 'update'],
    [['status'], function ($attribute) {
        $this->$attribute = \yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process($this->$attribute);
    }],
];
```

The problem is that if the content is `<script>alert('something')</script>`, it will be blank due to purifier and the content will pass the required validation.

So how can I revalidate the content for require? Or what is the good way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Validation rules are processed one after another so just put the second one as first.

```
return [
    ['status', 'filter', 'filter' => function ($value) {
        return \yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process($value);
    }],
    ['status', 'required', 'on' => 'update'],
];
```

Comment: [['status'], 'filter', 'filter' => '\yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process']